# scipy UDF error when migrating to Spark 1.6

Tags: scipy, pyspark

I started migrating from Spark 1.5 (Python) to Spark 1.6 and for some reason the following commands does not work anymore :

```
from scipy.stats import binom
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
BCDF = lambda Ps : binom.cdf(Ps[0],Ps[1],Ps[2])
sqlContext.udf.register('bcdf', BCDF, FloatType())
```

It yields the error :

```
no module named _tkinter
```

I tested my scipy function was still working, everything as expected on that front.

Did anyone experienced a similar issue ?

Best

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons importing stats rather than binom directly did the trick for me :

```
from scipy import stats
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
BCDF = lambda Ps : stats.binom.cdf(Ps[0],Ps[1],Ps[2])
sqlContext.udf.register('bcdf', BCDF, FloatType())
```